# Power of 2 bit operator in Java?

Tags: java, enums, bitwise-operators

I have a int variable to save the option, that may include none, one or many sub-options like this:

```
public static final int OPERATOR_PLUS = 1;
public static final int OPERATOR_SUBTRACT = 2;
public static final int OPERATOR_MULTIPLY = 4;
public static final int OPERATOR_DIVIDE = 8;
```

And I need a function that will return if that variant contains a sub-option. I tried:

```
return (Operator & Operators);
return (Operator && Operators);
```

But Eclipse says both of them are grammar errors (both Operator and Operators are int). Please tell me how to use AND Bit operator in Java. In .NET, I use: `Operator And Operators`.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's because of the return type (boolean). I didn't know & operator return an int value type. Thanks all :)! Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the return type of your method? If it is `boolean`, then you should write it like this:

```
public boolean hasOperatorBit() {
    return (Operator & Operators) != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Java won't treat an `int` as a `boolean` (unlike C++, AFAIU). Try

```
return (Operator & Operators) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is the *bitwise* AND operator, and should be valid syntax, so long as the return type of your method is `int`, or something equivalent.  If you want a boolean return type, you'll need to do something like `return (operator & operators) != 0;`.

The second one is not valid; it's a *logical* AND operator, so both of its arguments need to be `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare your variable with the operator in question using bitwise AND to see if that is equivalent to the operator.

Eg,

return OPERATOR_PLUS & operators == OPERATOR_PLUS;

Because if you think about how bitwise works, you want to say does my variable contain the bit flag for the operator.

Answer (score 0):

The first line would be correct to check that, whereas you can only check one operator possibility at a time. Furthermore you have to check whether the result is not equal to 0 to be correct.

```
return ((operator & sub_operator) != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean checkOperator(int operators, int operator) {
 return (operators & operator) != 0;
}
```

[Tutorials](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/0300__Bitwise-Operators.htm) for better understanding.